# Lazy loading Infragistics Ultragrid

Tags: .net, winforms, lazy-loading, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Does anyone know if the Infragistics UltraGrid for Windows Forms support lazy loading? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done with the Infragistics WinForm.

Comment: These links are both dead now. FWIW, Stackoverflow answers are supposed to have the actual meat of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used to lazy-load the data in my grids.

1. Create a `UltraGrid`.
2. Bind it to a `UltraDataSource` control.
3. Handle the [`CellDataRequested`](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/HTML/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinDataSource.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinDataSource.UltraDataSource~CellDataRequested_EV.html) of the [`UltraDataSource`](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/HTML/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinDataSource.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinDataSource.UltraDataSource.html). Here you can put in your own code to lazy load the data from your external data source, a web service, database, etc.

Comment: How do you handle filtering and sorting ?